# Black screen when booting Ubuntu and windows 7 in virtual-box on a windows 10 computer

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I have a new windows 10 computer I want to use Ubuntu in my virtual machine sadly when I run the virtual machine I have a black screen and it never boots. I also I have a windows 7 virtual machine and it has the same problem. They used to both work fine but on a certain day after rebooting the computer they both had the same problems. What can I do to fix it. Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to fix the issue.

I turned core isolation off.

[set core isolation to off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GHS0.png)